# How to properly implement a loop that includes awaitMessages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, discord.js

So basically I am creating a quick setup command for my discord bot. The idea is that it takes them through a series of prompts that allows them to choose the roles they want to have permissions to use which commands. The issue is that if (for some reason, it doesn't make a ton of sense because they are mentioning the role, but no stone left unturned when it comes to errors,) they choose a role that doesn't exist, it allows them to restart on that 'stage' of the command. I figured to do this I would need a loop, since ideally it allows them to infinitely retry if the role they keep choosing doesn't exist.

I have tried, and failed, a bunch of different `for/while` loops and `while` loops, but they all run out of memory, which I believe indicates that it keeps infinitely generating new `awaitMessages` instances.

This is the code that I have that currently works (without 'catching' the error)

```js
message.channel.send('Choose your moderator role.').then(async (modQ) => {
                        message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {maxMatches: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time']}).then(async (modC) => {
                            await modQ.delete()
                            await modC.first().delete()
                            let Found = modC.first().mentions.roles.first()
                            if (Found) {
                                let chosen = String(modC.first().mentions.roles.first().id)
                                setArgs(chosen, 'generalRoles', 'generalRole_id')
                            } else {
                                message.channel.send('No')
                            }
                        })
                    })
```

I am aware that the prompts and messages would take awhile each time, and in that time frame the loop could have run millions of times, but I honestly am out of ideas on how to achieve infinite retries on each 'stage.'

I would want the "Choose your moderator role" message sent each time, and deleted after a role has been chosen (successfully or unsuccessfully,) and if the role is valid, for it to go to the `if (Found)` part, and if the role is invalid, for it to loop back around and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to figure it out through some work, and since it seems others have this issue as well, instead of deleting, I will answer.

So here is the code I have that is working:

```js
message.channel.send(mod).then(async (modQ) => {
                        message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {maxMatches: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time']}).then(async (modC) => {
                            await modQ.delete()
                            await modC.first().delete()
                            let Found = modC.first().mentions.roles.first()
                            let found = false;
                            if (Found) {
                                found = true;
                                let chosen = String(modC.first().mentions.roles.first().id)
                                setArgs(chosen, 'generalRoles', 'generalRole_id')
                                console.log('worked1')
                            } else {
                                while (found === false) {
                                    await message.channel.send('Hey').then(async (modQ) => {
                                        await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {maxMatches: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time']}).then(async (modC) => {
                                            await modQ.delete()
                                            await modC.first().delete()
                                            let Found = modC.first().mentions.roles.first()
                                            if (Found) {
                                                let chosen = String(modC.first().mentions.roles.first().id)
                                                setArgs(chosen, 'generalRoles', 'generalRole_id')
                                                console.log('worked2')
                                                found = true
                                            }
                                        })
                                    })
                                }
                            }
                            if (found === true) {
                                message.channel.send('We here now.')
                            }
                        })
                    })
```

Hope this can help someone!